# What's the radius of the explosion caused by a single reactor ignition of the Death Star superlaser?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, death-star

Twice in Rogue One,

> Only a single core of the Death Star is activated in order to wipe out large parts of planets without completely destroying them.

What's the radius of these explosions?

Comment: The movie never shows the final result of the blast. The scenes cut off while it was still expanding. Really curious if novelization gives any numbers.

Comment: Perhaps there's documentation elsewhere? IDK where to look

Comment: Are you asking what the radius of a detonating Death Star is? Or what the radius of the Death Star "laser" detonation? I think I know which you are speaking of but the question itself is a little ambiguous.

Comment: @Withywindle the question seems pretty obvious to me...unsure where the confusion is coming from

Comment: When a Blu-Ray releases, we can get a reference somewhere, how fast the earth-shattering wave is spreading per second (i.e. play 1s and compare the distance it traveled to something we know the size of, like a shuttle) and then just multiply by the number of seconds between the shot and the last frame that's showing the wave. That's our minimal radius.

Comment: @ChristianF97 "What's the radius of a Death Star detonation?" If we redact "single-core" the question can be interpreted either way - and I think it actually leans towards the explosion (detonation) of the DS itself. "Single-core" is equally non-descriptive as we aren't talking about a single core DS, we are talking about a single core shot from the DS superlaser.

Answer (score 6):

## Spoilers Ahead! Warning

I'm going to take a stab at this through by inferring information through various canon sources.

1. The moon Jedha is 11,263 km/d [<sup>1</sup>](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedha)
2. The *Dauntless Imperial-class* Star Destroyer is 7,000 m
3. Saw Garreras' hideout, The Holy City, The Catacombs of Cadera, is in visual distance of Jedha.
4. According to this picture, the *Dauntless* appears to be about equal length of the city of Jedha. Maybe along the lines of 5996 meters as opposed to 7,000m

   [image]
5. We could the infer that the circumference of the city had 18839 meters with an total area of 28236647.336836 m<sup>2</sup>
6. Now considering that Jedha was visible from the Holy City , The Catacombs of Cad era when we see this:

   [image]
7. And then we see this!

   [image]

Perhaps someone with some engineering background would be able to help me nail this one down. Thanks!

Comment: The ejecta and explosion in the last pic are in space.... probably something like 2000km in height.  The blast radius itself is probably quite small - maybe 1500km.  But the damage radius would be much larger - 20-30000km.  Guessing though.  But yeah, those guys watching from Cad era are fried.

Comment: The best would be to take the last pic to calc the radius?

Comment: Where do you get that the Dauntless was 7000 m long? All references I've seen have the Imperial I at 1600 m.

Comment: @quantumswing  I referenced the Rogue One visual dictionary, however I may have made an error in transcription. I'll check after work and come back. I've been meaning to finally answer this question anyway. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: uh. That's an imperial-class Star destroyer, probably imperial-1, which was 1,600 meters long. that makes jedha about a Km across. Im not sure what a dauntless-class SD is but most of the BBY starships were smaller than a ISD.